# Fatal error but i don't see any broken syntax or errors with my funciton

Tags: php, arrays, function, magento

On this line here:

```
$gtotal = (float)number_format($gorder()->getSubtotal(),2);
```

I'm receiving this error on my success.phtml page on line 77. I don't see anything wrong with it at all.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Function name must be a string
>
> /var/www/app/design/frontend/tw/ff16/template/checkout/success.phtml:77
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /var/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include() #1
>   /var/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272):
>   Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/t...') #2
>   /var/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286):
>   Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView() #3
>   /var/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(923):
>   Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml() #4
>   /var/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43):
>   Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml() #5
>   /var/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(923):
>   Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml() #6
>   /var/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(641):
>   Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml() #7
>   /var/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(585):
>   Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true) #8
>   /var/www/app/design/frontend/tw/ff16/template/page/1column.phtml(51):
>   M in
>   /var/www/app/design/frontend/tw/ff16/template/checkout/success.phtml
>   on line 77

Do i need to wrap in `[]`?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Is it the parenthesis on $gorder?

Comment: I think it may be @Doug. I'll give it a test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the parenthesis from $gorder so you have this instead:

```
$gtotal = (float)number_format($gorder->getSubtotal(),2);
```

Comment: Well, I'm not throwing that error anymore. Also, i noticed that after i wrote that code there was two pixels on my success.phtml page below that... that were no longer working. I'm assuming that's the reason why.